# How to make Windows not complain about an Ext formatted USB stick?

Tags: linux, windows, usb-flash-drive, formatting, format

I have a USB stick that is ext4 formatted, for use between a bunch of Linux systems. How can I make the Windows "You must format" dialog not pop up any more, so that anybody else does not by accident format my data? One of the Linux systems it's used on is a VM on Windows...

Comment: Depending on how it's accessed by the VM you might be able to just remove the drive letter in windows.

Comment: It doesn't get a drive letter in Windows as it has no Windows-readable partitions on it. That's what causes Windows to say "This device is unusable for me, let's format it?".

Comment: I've only ever seen that message if I clicked on a partition that had a drive letter but no readable file system. You could try to include a miniature FAT32 partition. Windows would have something to read and would maybe ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which virtualization product you are using, but in many cases you can configure the host to automatically assign a specific USB device (aka this stick) to the VM.
If you can do that, the Windows host will not attempt to figure out what file system is on the stick at all and the stick will be inaccessible for the host.

Comment: It's Virtualbox and I think this may be the best solution yet. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: VirtualBox is certainly capable of doing this. Section 3.10 of the manual explains how to do this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

[Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) is a Windows file system driver for the Ext2, Ext3, and Ext4 file systems. It allows Windows to read Linux file systems natively, providing access to the file system via a drive letter that any program can access.

Comment: So the op needs to install that on every computer?

Comment: I have no reason for Windows to access it in the first place - in fact, I'd like to keep it inaccessible for Windows. @Seth's suggestion would be better than that, but that would lead to a second partition showing up in Linux too.